# Получить ключи и значения словаря из json объекта

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, json, словари

строка

```
{"043b2c896b034212b49e1793d94c0654":6.589013,"09ff8de9f03640e0a4ee16c3e9140088":428.830673}
```

нужны данные в ковычках и после :
т.е.

```
043b2c896b034212b49e1793d94c0654  
6.589013  
09ff8de9f03640e0a4ee16c3e9140088  
428.830673
```

как будет выглядеть регулярное выражение?

Comment: Какая регулярка, если это у вас json, кажется!

Comment: по сути вам просто надо все кроме {}" - `[^{}"]+`

Comment: для вашей строки dic = json.loads(json_string), где dic - словарь

Comment: Зачем регулярка-то? Это ж обычный словарь.

Comment: разобрался спасибо. dic = json.loads(json_string), где dic - словарь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Вариант через json:

```
import json
d = json.loads('{"043b2c896b034212b49e1793d94c0654":6.589013,"09ff8de9f03640e0a4ee16c3e9140088":428.830673}')
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

Результат:

```
043b2c896b034212b49e1793d94c0654
6.589013
09ff8de9f03640e0a4ee16c3e9140088
428.830673
```

---

#### Вариант через ast:

```
import ast
d = ast.literal_eval('{"043b2c896b034212b49e1793d94c0654":6.589013,"09ff8de9f03640e0a4ee16c3e9140088":428.830673}')
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

Результат:

```
043b2c896b034212b49e1793d94c0654
6.589013
09ff8de9f03640e0a4ee16c3e9140088
428.830673
```

---

#### Вариант через регулярки:

```
import re

text = '{"043b2c896b034212b49e1793d94c0654":6.589013,"09ff8de9f03640e0a4ee16c3e9140088":428.830673}'

for i in re.findall('([\d\w\.]+)', text):
    print(i)
```

Результат:

```
043b2c896b034212b49e1793d94c0654
6.589013
09ff8de9f03640e0a4ee16c3e9140088
428.830673
```

Comment: если ввод json, то не следует `ast.literal_eval()` использовать. С regex дело не в сложности, а в том что можно легко разные случаи пропустить (`1e-1`). То есть regex только в тех случаях подходит, когда других вариантов нет (нельзя ни json парсер запустить, ни свой реализовать) -- в ограниченных окружениях.

Comment: @jfs, я согласен